When wiring up a usb port without a hub, how do you wire up a current limit switch?
I'm challenging myself to make a CM4 carrierboard, mostly by just taking the bits of the CM4 IO board that I'm interested in and leaving the rest.

I've seen that the CM4 only has a single USB2 "channel" (controller? - there is only a single D+/D-), and the various other usb ports are achieved via a USB hub chip.
I've decided to remove that hub and just have a single usb port on my board (going directly into the cpu).
It seems like a good idea however, to keep the "Current limit switch", unfortunately, without the hub, I'm not sure where to hook the "nFault" pin to, nor the "EN" pin.
My understanding from the datasheet (https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/DIOD_S_A0010880137_1-2543666.pdf) is that the EN pin will allow power to flow from the "OUT" pin when set high.
And the fault pin will normally be high, and go low I guess if too much current is drawn?
Could the EN pin be simply hooked up to some power source and the fault tied to gnd? or would that defeat the purpose of the thing?
Is this the wrong current limit switch for the job?
Do I need to look for some sort of usb hub without-the-hub, or just bite the bullet and keep the hub in the schematic?


I assume you mean Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4. Per CM4 datasheet, this board does not have any dedicated (pre-programmed) pins to control the Hi-side power switch, nor any input to sense the port overcurrent fault.
If you want to make things right, you should not enable the downstream VBUS power until your board gets powered up and boots into OS and has the USB stack enabled and running. Therefore you should dedicate one of presumably configurable GPIO output to pull it up only after your USB stack is ready. How would you accomplish this, I have little idea.
If you boldly enable this pin from some power rail right away, a connected device will pull D+ high before anything is ready and possibly confuse the CM4 USB PHY. In the past some USB2 hosts were confused with unexpected initial state of D+/D- wires and failed to operate. That's why USB specifications require USB devices to not have anything on D+/D- until VBUS goes high. It is however possible that RPi is tolerant to this, and the power-derived pullup on EN pin will cause no trouble.
Now, to make use of the overcurrent fault flag, you should dedicate another pin as input, and hook it to the nFault pin of the power IC. And if this signal goes LOW, it should alert your run-time code of the overcurrent event and prompt for some user actions.

Yeah I did think a software solution was a possibility, but I was hoping for a "plug and play" approach where I wouldn't need special software in order to use the carrier board properly.
But this approach does sound doable, I'd have to figure out how to plug some sort of script or program into linux, should be a fairly well documented process.
I'm guessing if the fault pin triggers, I should also disable the VBUS, effectively cutting off power to the USB port?

@DanForever, "should also disable the VBUS, effectively cutting off power to the USB port?" - Yes, this is the correct way, although the IC will enter "current limiting" mode if overcurrent is detected. The IC might become too hot if you don't disable it.

If you want to just always enable the output, tie enable to 5V supply input. Or 3.3V supply so it is on after 3.3V is up.  You can control the port from an IO pin if you want.
If you want to ignore the overcurrent event, you can do nothing on the fault pin. It can be grounded. But if you want to detect a fault, you can wire it into an IO pin with a pull-up.
